# Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php on line 973

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to send an email from my wordpress website using the function wp_mail and I am getting this error:

```
Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php on line 973 0
```

I don't really understand why I am getting it.

This is my current code:

```
// Contact form  Ajax 

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_contact_form', 'submit_contact_form'); 

function submit_contact_form(){

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];       
        $email_to = "info@yyy.com";

        $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";
        $username = 'myEmail@gmail.uk';
        $password = 'mypassword';

        $email_subject = "You have a new email from $email via yyy.com website";
        $message = $_POST['text']; 

        $headers = array ('From' => $email, 'To' => $email_to,'Subject' => $email_subject);
        /*$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
          array ('host' => $host,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password));*/

        //$mail = $smtp->send($email_to, $headers, $message);

        wp_mail( $email_to, $headers, $message );

        /*if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
          echo($mail->getMessage());
        } else {
          echo("Message successfully sent!\n");
        }*/
    }
}



error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: There is no trim call in this code! Your error is here `class-phpmailer.php on line 973`

Comment: I'm not a hardcore wordpress pro, but i'm guessing it's being used in html/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php on line 973 that wp_mail() function  is using.

Comment: I think you have the arguments in the wrong order see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail (`<?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); ?> `)

Comment: I called the 'subject' parameter 'header'. I don't think this is the cause

Comment: Here is your error! `$headers` has to be a string!

Comment: The WP reference says that `$headers` can also be an array, shouldn't be about that.

Comment: Try this: `wp_mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);`

Comment: @numsu Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762123/warning-trim-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-array-given-in-wp-includes-cla#comment45803924_28762123 He uses `$headers` as subject argument!

Comment: I need more coffee i guess.. 
i changed it to: `wp_mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);` and tried `wp_mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message);` and got `0` from the chrome 'network' responce... no emails :X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed a package called "PostFix" which is responsible for sending emails from an Ubuntu server (which is the servers linux I use), and it solved the problem!