# Why wp_mail() function isn't sending any emails and displaying '0' in Chrome 'Network' response

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to send emails through wordpress using wp_mail() function and it doesn't seem to work.

It's displaying `0` in Chrome 'Network' response
with

```
Status Code:200 OK
```

[image]

this my code part:

```
// Contact form  Ajax 

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_contact_form', 'submit_contact_form'); 

function submit_contact_form(){

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];       
        $email_to = "info@company.com";

        $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";
        $username = 'myEmail@company.pro';
        $password = 'passpass';

        $email_subject = "You have a new email from $email via company.com website";
        $message = $_POST['text']; 

        $headers = array ('From' => $email, 'To' => $email_to,'Subject' => $email_subject);
        /*$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
          array ('host' => $host,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password));*/

        //$mail = $smtp->send($email_to, $headers, $message);

        wp_mail( $email_to, $email_subject, $message );

        /*if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
          echo($mail->getMessage());
        } else {
          echo("Message successfully sent!\n");
        }*/
    }
}





error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

What part might be wrong?

Comment: Seems pretty similar to your last one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28762123/3933332 ? Don't you think too?

Comment: no, I'm not using $header + i get a different error. wordpress first example shows it should work like this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Comment: Why didn't you updated your last question? You can use the edit button

Comment: 2 different errors. It might help people who google their questions like me and actually find a relevant post..

Comment: You don't have to edit your post after you fix your error. 
if you get an other error so it's a different issue - thumbs up :)

Comment: It's returning `0` because you're not returning anything. Try: `echo json_encode(array("result"=>"complete"));wp_die();` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post this as an official answer:

Two things you should check:

1) The response is 0 because you're not returning anything. You should be returning a ajax response, usually json_encoding your request like this helps:

```
 if(wp_mail($email_to,$email_subject,$message)) {
   echo json_encode(array("result"=>"complete"));
 } else {
   echo json_encode(array("result"=>"mail_error"));
 }
 wp_die();`
```

2) Not all wordpress/server configurations allow the default Wordpress wp_mail function to send out mail. Certainly when testing on a local(host) server, lots of ISP's block the default outgoing mail traffic (and in another question I've noticed you're using SMTP mail-functions). Sometimes the blocking goes on silently, so it looks like everything works, but mail never gets sent. What helps is to install the [WP Mail SMTP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) (or similar) so you can configure outgoing SMTP servers (with or without authentication).

Comment: 1) I get: `0: {result: "mail_error"}`

(no  `0`  error anymore because there was no `exit;` or `die();` function.)
It seems like it gets all the parameters right, and something gets wrong with the `wp_mail()` function. ---

2) I am transferring my website from a regular HTML website to WordPress and the old code I used was with SMTP - So what i'm trying to do now is making it work with the build in wordpress functions, and prefer not installing any plugins and learn to build them by myself. I want to know how things work on wordpress and expand my knowledge..

Comment: Could this be maybe because I wrote the function in the functions.php file and not as a plugin or something like that?

Comment: I get your thoughts and understand your choice not to use any pre-made third party plugins. As far as I can see everything you've done is perfect, but the wp_mail function is not returning `true`, thus not sending mail. Unfortunately thats as far as wordpress error reporting goes for wp_mail. Chad Butler has written some interesting posts on this matter, including possible solutions and also a guide how to write your own SMTP code: http://www.butlerblog.com/2013/09/24/troubleshooting-the-wp_mail-function/ - please let us know if and how your issues work out.

Comment: I installed a package called "PostFix" which is responsible for emails sent from an Ubuntu server (which is the servers linux I use), and it solved the problem! Thank you Eric Mahieu for your help!   :D